# chmod - website visitors file access permissions

Tags: php

Sorry for possibly duplicate and simple question...

Lets say some website-visitor wants to download this (`http://my.ip.add.ress/project/files/foo.txt`) file. So if visitor has **read** permision he/she can download it, otherwise he/she can not.

**My question :**
When I change mode of `foo.txt` with `chmod xyz foo.txt`, which one of x,y and z is for visitor permissions?

I dont understand the 3rd digit **z** which is called **world** sometimes. Maybe z is for visitor permissions. :|

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Web authentication has nothing to do with the filesystem of your web server.

Answer (score 0):

World means not the owner and not the member of the files group. It isnt' related to "world". In this sense "world" is the webserver process runner user. Sometimes www-data or httpd.
So you have to manage to this user can read the file.

But if you would like to restrict this read permission to only a subset of users you have to hide the file at first from general users, make it readable by the webserver, and create something to verify if the user is enabled to read or not.

If you google for .htaccess you can find similar examples, but there are lots of other solutions also.